# Why doesn't "graph.facebook.com/:page_id/insights" return anything?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

However urls one level deep like `/insights/page_engaged_users`, `/insights/page_consumptions` etc. return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, this absolutely should work, and it used to. It's broken right now. A bug was filed at 1:46am for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/226310404141320

Please go to that bug and subscribe and also reproduce it so that Facebook will fast-track fixing this.

Comment: Note, if you query using fql, you should be able to get whatever stats you need. That still appears to be working.

Comment: Looks like the bug fix will go live at the end of today!